# how can I find the Min and Max with a for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, minmax

hi I have problem in my code I'm trying to find the minimum height of a plant and the max height of the plant with a for loop  but I'm running into a problem and I cant solve it (this in C# BTW)
the code:

```
int i;
double height, min, max;
Console.WriteLine("Insert the height of plant");
height = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
min = 0;
max = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
{
    height = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if(height >= max)
    {
        height = max;
    }
    if(height < max)
    {
        height = min;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Maximum hight = {0}", max);
Console.WriteLine("Minimum hight = {0}", min);
```

Comment: _" but I'm running into a problem "_ and the problem is? =)

Comment: Also try to [debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022) your code - that will help you to find what is causing the issue.

Comment: `min` and `max` are never changed because you have them reversed with `height`. `X = Y` assigns the value of `Y` to `X`.

Comment: In addition to the other troubles mentioned, I see you set min when testing max in one of the if's.

Comment: `min = height;`, not `height = min;`

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. For the future please try and include into your question a much more precise problem description. You can always start with 1) Expected outcome: ... 2) Real outcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your starting `min` and `max` to be the same as the initial input. Then, as you loop, compare those to see if the values are larger or smaller than the current `min`/`max`:

```
double height, min, max;
Console.WriteLine("Insert the height of plant");
height = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
min = height;
max = height;

for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
{
    height = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (height > max)
        max = height;
    if (height < min)
        min = height;
}
Console.WriteLine("Maximum hight = {0}", max);
Console.WriteLine("Minimum hight = {0}", min);
```

As suggested by Dmitry, you can even reduce your `for` loop to this to simply return the smaller/larger number into `min`/`max`:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
{
    height = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    max = Math.Max(max, height);
    min = Math.Min(min, height);
}
```

Comment: Or `max = Math.Max(max, height);`

Comment: `min = height;` *before* the loop deserves +1

Comment: thanks for the help man appreciate it :)